# web url forwarding to different port and subdirectory

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, domain-forwarding

I would like to forward anyone going to subdomain.old-domain.com:8014 to this new address subdomain.new-domain.com:8000/subdirectory (note a different domain AND different port PLUS a subdirectory)

Is it possible in a web host (such as Bluehost) using cPanel DNS Editor or some form of URL redirection with port redirect included?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if Bluehost allows port redirection using an [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.old-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8014$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.new-domain.com:8000/subdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```